# Issues creating inheritance with fluent NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I trying to create inheritance so I can have some super classes with general properties and then more specialized classes that are the ones getting used.

I want something like the Table per type or table per class they make here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat

So I have my supertype Game here

```
    public abstract class Game
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserGame> UserList { get; set; }
}

public class GameMap : ClassMap<Game>
{
    public GameMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "GameId")
            .GeneratedBy
            .HiLo("100");
        HasMany(x => x.UserList)
           .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

And then my specialized class here QMGameActive

```
    public class QMGameActive : Game
{
    public virtual DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public virtual string SelectedBrick { get; set; }
    public virtual int Score { get; set; }
    public virtual string History { get; set; }
    public virtual int StartingPlayerId { get; set; }

    public QMGameActive() 
    {
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        History = "";
        SelectedBrick = "";
    }
}

public class QMGameActiveMap : SubclassMap<QMGameActive>
{
    public QMGameActiveMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("GameId");
        Map(x => x.LastUpdate);
        Map(x => x.SelectedBrick);
        Map(x => x.Score);
        Map(x => x.History);
        Map(x => x.StartingPlayerId);
    }
}
```

But when I get a diagram from the server I can see there is no connection between Game and QMGameActive there

[image]

So what am I missing to make it use inheritance?

Comment: what is the point of having this inheritance and creating a Game table with nothing but the Id?

Comment: Right now there is only one game in my database, but later on there will be multiple Games, each of them will inherit from Game which is the "supertype" and I will also make more subtypes as there will also be a QMGameInActive and I want my database diagram to look like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/mapping-strategies-fluent/4.png if possible

Comment: you might want to read up on this: http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure that if you KeyColumn("GameId"); from the QMGameActiveMap() then  NHibernate will generate QMGameActive with an ID Column of GameID which will be a foreign key of  Game.GameId. which would seem to give you what you want.

(sorry away from home and cannot try code out to make sure).

Comment: But I already have the KeyColumn("GameId"); in the QMGameActiveMap ? And that makes no difference if its their or not, just creates that "Index" you see in the picture